# Python selenium compound class name not permitted

Tags: python, selenium

I am using this:

```
namehover = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('fullname show-popup-with-id')
```

to select this:

```
<strong class="fullname show-popup-with-id " data-aria-label-part="">Jayson</strong>
```

However it says 'compound class names not permitted'. Does anyone know what I should change? Thanks